# Can't access Port 9200 Remotely

Tags: elasticsearch

Have just started using elastic search 5.4.0, first i have  installed it on Mac(local) and then in server.
In Mac when i am running in browser as  'http://localhost:9200' it is showing me output :

```js
{
  "name" : "Node_1",
  "cluster_name" : "bhujang_bipl",
  "cluster_uuid" : "N75mGOiSQCufpBl_2B7jSg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

which means i am connected to 9200 which is elasticsaerch.

But when i am running it on server by http://192.168.1.126:9200 , then it is not getting connected and shows me an output as :page not found !!

I disabled firewall on both the server and client as solutions I got from internet but couldn't get it working.

My elasticsaerch.yml file is

```js
 
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#network.host:192.168.1.126
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
#The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]","103.240.195.45","103.240.195.45"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Can anyone help me with what can be the best possible mistake from my side ?

Comment: You should uncomment the line `#network.host:192.168.1.126` by removing `#` in your `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Comment: I have tried uncomment the line #network.host:192.168.1.126 by removing # in my elasticsearch.yml file but after that elasticsearch has stopped running .

Comment: What is there in elasticsearch server log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19987

add this two line in the yml file

```
transport.host: localhost
network.host: 192.168.1.126
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me remotely, it's hosted on Azure windows 2019 server. I have opened port ranges 9200-9300

```
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
#network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: 192.168.1.126
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,content-Type,content-Length
```