# OpenShift - Route doesn't connect to pod

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, openshift

I'm currently having issues exposing a pod running in an openshift 4 environment.
The attempt to connect to `https://route...` results in an 503.

```
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: app-elastic-route
  namespace: app-test
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: app-elastic-svc
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 9200-es
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-elastic-svc
  namespace: app-test
spec:
  ports:
    - name: 9200-es
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    app: app-elastic
    type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
```

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: app-deploy
  namespace: app-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-elastic
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: app-elastic
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: application-config
          configMap:
            name: app-config
            items:
              - key: application.properties
                path: application.properties
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 750m
              memory: 1Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500Mi
          name: app-elastic
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: application-config
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /config
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          image: >-
            elastic/elasticsearch:7.14.0
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: { }
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

I have the exact same setup running an port 8080 for a spring boot app and this works fine!

I'm positive the pod is alive, when connecting to the pod itself `curl localhost:9200` works fine!

Can someone please provide some pointers on what might be wrong, or how I can investigate this issue in more detail?!

Answer (score 0):

In your`Route`,`port.targetPort`should be 8080

https -> route:443 -> service:8080 -> pods:9200

Comment: The Route targetPort points to actual Pod containerPort so in this case it should be 9200.

Answer (score 0):

In your service, change the  **spec.ports[0].port to 9200** instead of 8080 an it should work .

Comment: I tried all 8 combinations... Route=["8080","9200"]x Service=["8080/8080","9200/9200","8080/9200","9200/8080"] Is there any way to inspect the traffic somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my service and route configuration was correct.
In fact the pod was not corrctlty behaving on the port...

Honestly I don't understand the details but I had to change configuration of the pod with elasticsearch.yml

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 8080
transport.tcp.port: 9200
transport.host: localhost
```

The following links helped me:

[Can't access Port 9200 Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889492/cant-access-port-9200-remotely)

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19987